# Sort list of dicts by specific list of values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to code a faster way to solve the following problem but I don't know how to do it:

I have the following list of dicts and list of identifiers:

```
list_of_dicts = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'A'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'B'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'C'}, {'id': 4, 'name': 'D'}]
list_of_ids = [1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 3, 4]
```

I'd like to have the following output:

```
[{'id': 1, 'name': 'A'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'C'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'B'}, {'id': 4, 'name': 'D'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'A'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'C'}, {'id': 4, 'name': 'D'}]
```

The way I'm doing it is:

```
list_of_dict_ids = [d['id'] for d in list_of_dicts]
ordered_list_by_ids = [list_of_dicts[list_of_dict_ids.index(i)] for i in list_of_ids]
```

Is there any faster way to do it?

Comment: you can re-map your list_of_dicts by id: `by_id = {d["id"]: d for d in list_of_dicts}`, then you can simply map the list_of_ids to your output: `ordered_list_by_ids = [by_id[id] for id in list_of_ids]`

Comment: What's wrong with `[{'id': i} for i in list_of_ids]`?

Comment: There could be other things or keys in the dict `[{'id': 1, 'name': 'A'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'B'}, ...]`

Comment: Please clarify this in the question and/or choose a better example to avoid trivial answers like this.

Comment: Sorry. I've modified the question. I think the answer of @njzk2 works perfect

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this :

```
dic = {d["id"]: d for d in list_of_dicts}
dic
>>>{1: {'id': 1}, 2: {'id': 2}, 3: {'id': 3}, 4: {'id': 4}}
lst =[dic[i] for i in list_of_ids]
lst
>>>[{'id': 1}, {'id': 3}, {'id': 2}, {'id': 4}, {'id': 1}, {'id': 3}, {'id': 4}]
```